# django inclusion tag kwargs error says "function takes 2 arguments"

Tags: django, templates, django-custom-tags

I have written inclusion tag, it take context and *args and **kwargs

```
@register.inclusion_tag('template.html', takes_context=True)
def my_tag(a, b, *args, **kwargs):
    print 'Kwargs: '
    return .....
```

**template:**

```
  {% my_tag 1 1 2 page=10 %}

Error message:
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

my_tag takes 2 arguments
```

whats wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found the issue, The problem *args and **kwargs are implemented in Django 1.4 but I was trying this feature in Django 1.3.1 so that is the reason it shows such kind of errors

for more clarity check the Django 1.4 release notes. [Django1.4 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have put `takes_context=True`, the first parameter to the function must be `context`.